# What does MUNU ムヌ mean please as in the phrase below

Tags: translation, katakana

Can anyone tell me what "munu" means in this phrase, please?

> 夏が来る前に秋になったような変なムヌで...

Comment: Im not too sure if this is the answer, but it appears to be a dialectal word meaning もの, spoken in 与論島 (よろんじま) , an island in the Pacific controlled from 鹿児島県 (かごしまけん). Source: http://app.m-cocolog.jp/t/typecast/98523/87956/56674239 it was a very hard read for me, so please look for yourself to see it helps :)

Comment: What is the source?

Comment: ムヌ is not in average native speakers' vocabulary. Maybe it's an OCR error for 夜?

Answer (score 2):

Probably, ムヌ is a misreading of もの.
So the original sentence should be as follows:
夏が来る前に秋になったような変なもので.
It was a strange situation like the autumn had come before the summer.

In Japanese, "もの" is often used as the meaning "situation,circumstance".

In written Japanese, もの and ムヌ are not alike, but in the spoken language, both of them sound very similar, especially in local dialects.